# Xamarin - "Funny RefName" when publishing to BitBucket

Tags: git, xamarin, bitbucket, xamarin-studio

I am sorry that this is a duplicate of other questions, however even though I know the "answer", I do not know how to implement it.

I am using Xamarin and version control.  I was able to set it up to work locally just fine. However, when I try to push my changes to the remote server, BitBucket.org, I get an error "Funny RefName".

After extensively googling this, I know the answer is I need to set the Target Ref Name from "master" or "refs/heads/master" however I have no clue where I have to set this.

Under "Version Control" -> "Manage Branches" it lists my one branch of "master".  If I click edit and try to change it to "refs/heads/master", it says it already exists.  Under remote sources it has "origin", however if i change that to "refs/heads/origin" it allows me to do so, but same error when pushing to server.

For reference this is a duplicate / extension of:
[funny refname error when creating a new remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792205/funny-refname-error-when-creating-a-new-remote-branch)

It was also asked by someone on Xamarin's forum with the same solution, but again does not explain how/where to set this:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5213/error-funny-refname-git

I appreciate any help that could be offered on this

Comment: same problem here, did anyone find the solution?

Comment: No and I asked several places. My solution is probably going to be opening it in Parallels using Visual Studio and using that for GIT.  Not the best, but at least my coding will be synced then.

Comment: my workaround for now is just simply using git command line for commits and pushing.

Comment: not bad. probably easier to just make a macro i run in my toolbar for that.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more of a workaround than a solution, but it might help some people, especially git beginners.

I'm simply using git command line for commits and pushes. As far as you can commit from Xamarin, in my case it takes really long time. If this doesn't happen for you, whenever you want to push, you can just write:

```
git push -u origin master
```

And for making commits outside IDE:

```
git commit -am 'commit message'
```

Comment: While this is not actually the answer to the question, i will mark it until it is is actually answered since this solved my problem. I believe the upload was just to big because future posts have worked since then.  Thanks!